# VsCode - Command + Left Click Does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use vscode for developing react applications. I was able to go definitions when I click command + left click. But I can't do that anymore. I want to go into a function in another js file but I can not do that anymore.

What did I try to solve the problem?

1. I removed all of the extensions.
2. I downloaded the latest versions of vscode.
3. I tried to press F12 or option button but they are not working as well.

My settings:

[image: My settings]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you instead get two cursors when doing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+LBM?

Maybe you should set your Multi Cursor modifier to alt (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd>, as it may override the goto definition.